# (Typescript setup) 3D model custom layer not displayed in the mapbox

Tags: typescript, mapbox-gl-js, gltf

I've tried to recreate this sample using typescript but didn't succeed on it:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/

The expected behavior of the source code repo should be to display the 3D model on the mapbox. However, what is actually happening is that the gltf model is not showing up on the coordinate indicated.

please checkout the source code in this link:
https://github.com/MiguelG97/mapbox3dmodel

```
import mapboxgl, {
  CustomLayerInterface,
} from "mapbox-gl";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/Addons.js";

interface Mtransform {
  translateX: number;
  translateY: number;
  translateZ: number | undefined;
  rotateX: number;
  rotateY: number;
  rotateZ: number;
  scale: number;
}

export class CustomIFCLayer
  implements CustomLayerInterface
{
  static gltfData:
    | ArrayBuffer
    | { [key: string]: any };
  id: string;
  type: "custom";
  renderingMode?: "2d" | "3d" | undefined;
  camera: THREE.Camera = new THREE.Camera();
  scene: THREE.Scene = new THREE.Scene();
  map: mapboxgl.Map | null = null;
  renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer | null = null;

  modelTransform: Mtransform;
  modelAltitude = 0;
  modelRotate = [Math.PI / 2, 0, 0];
  constructor(coordinates: mapboxgl.LngLatLike) {
    this.id = "3d-ifc-model";
    this.type = "custom";
    this.renderingMode = "3d";
    const modelAsMercatorCoordinate =
      mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(
        coordinates,
        this.modelAltitude
      );
    this.modelTransform = {
      translateX: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.x,
      translateY: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.y,
      translateZ: modelAsMercatorCoordinate.z,
      rotateX: this.modelRotate[0],
      rotateY: this.modelRotate[1],
      rotateZ: this.modelRotate[2],
      /* Since our 3D model is in real world meters, a scale transform needs to be
       * applied since the CustomLayerInterface expects units in MercatorCoordinates.
       */
      scale:
        modelAsMercatorCoordinate.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits(),
    };
  }

  //once layer has been added to the Map
  async onAdd(
    map: mapboxgl.Map,
    gl: WebGL2RenderingContext
  ) {
    //ADD LIGHTS
    // const directionalLight =
    //   new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    // directionalLight.position
    //   .set(0, -70, 100)
    //   .normalize();
    // this.scene.add(directionalLight);
    // const directionalLight2 =
    //   new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    // directionalLight2.position
    //   .set(0, 70, 100)
    //   .normalize();
    // this.scene.add(directionalLight2);
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(
      0xffffff,
      1
    );
    this.scene.add(ambientLight);

    //add or fragments to the scene!
    //shouldn't we add the model to an existing map scene??
    //why it works creating a new webglrenderer that uses the mapbox canvas and webglcontext?
    //shouldn't they overlap each other with that approach??
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    const gltf = await loader.loadAsync(
      "./mydata.gltf" //"https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf"
    );
    console.log("my gltf: ", gltf);
    this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
    // const gltf = await loader.parseAsync(
    //   JSON.stringify(
    //     CustomIFCLayer.gltfData,
    //     null,
    //     2
    //   ),
    //   ""
    // );
    // const mesh = gltf.scene;
    // this.scene.add(mesh);
    // console.log("gltf loaded: ", mesh);
    //...

    this.map = map;
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: map.getCanvas(),
      context: gl,
      antialias: true,
    });
    this.renderer.autoClear = false;
  }
  render(
    gl: WebGL2RenderingContext,
    matrix: Array<number>
  ) {
    const rotationX =
      new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
        new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
        this.modelTransform.rotateX
      );
    const rotationY =
      new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
        this.modelTransform.rotateY
      );
    const rotationZ =
      new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
        this.modelTransform.rotateZ
      );
    const m = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(
      matrix
    );
    const l = new THREE.Matrix4()
      .makeTranslation(
        this.modelTransform.translateY,
        this.modelTransform.translateX,
        this.modelTransform.translateZ ?? 0
      )
      .scale(
        new THREE.Vector3(
          this.modelTransform.scale,
          -this.modelTransform.scale,
          this.modelTransform.scale
        )
      )
      .multiply(rotationX)
      .multiply(rotationY)
      .multiply(rotationZ);

    this.camera.projectionMatrix = m.multiply(l);
    if (this.renderer !== null) {
      this.renderer.resetState();
      this.renderer.render(
        this.scene,
        this.camera
      );
    }
    if (this.map !== null) {
      this.map.triggerRepaint();
    }
  }
  //optional
  prerender() {}
  onRemove() {}
}
const lng = -77.029499;
const lat = -12.120621;
const coordinates = new mapboxgl.LngLat(lng, lat);
mapboxgl.accessToken =
  "pk.eyJ1IjoibWlndWVsZzk3IiwiYSI6ImNsc21pa3lzazBseG0ycWw5b3p0amtidWYifQ.wrDaCxPiwdl55CofX8KXrg";

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map",
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10", //"mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9",
  projection: { name: "globe" }, // Display the map as a globe, since satellite-v9 defaults to Mercator
  zoom: 2,
  center: coordinates, //[lng,lat]
  antialias: true,
  pitch: 60,
});

const ifcLayer = new CustomIFCLayer(coordinates);
map.on("style.load", async () => {
  //i) add custom 3d model layer
  map.addLayer(ifcLayer, "waterway-label"); //"building"

  //ii) setup for planet UI
  map.setFog({
    color: "rgb(186, 210, 235)", // Lower atmosphere
    "high-color": "rgb(36, 92, 223)", // Upper atmosphere
    "horizon-blend": 0.02, // Atmosphere thickness (default 0.2 at low zooms)
    "space-color": "rgb(11, 11, 25)", // Background color
    "star-intensity": 0.6, // Background star brightness (default 0.35 at low zoooms )
  });
  //iii) add building extrusion layer
  const layers = map.getStyle().layers;
  const labelLayerId = layers.find(
    (layer) =>
      layer.type === "symbol" &&
      layer.layout !== undefined &&
      layer.layout["text-field"]
  )?.id;
  map.addLayer(
    {
      id: "add-3d-buildings",
      source: "composite",
      "source-layer": "building",
      filter: ["==", "extrude", "true"],
      type: "fill-extrusion",
      minzoom: 15,
      paint: {
        "fill-extrusion-color": "#aaa",
        "fill-extrusion-height": [
          "interpolate",
          ["linear"],
          ["zoom"],
          15,
          0,
          15.05,
          ["get", "height"],
        ],
        "fill-extrusion-base": [
          "interpolate",
          ["linear"],
          ["zoom"],
          15,
          0,
          15.05,
          ["get", "min_height"],
        ],
        "fill-extrusion-opacity": 0.6,
      },
    },
    labelLayerId
  );
  map.setLayoutProperty(
    "highlight",
    "visibility",
    "visible"
  );
});
map.on("load", () => {
  map.flyTo({
    center: coordinates,
    zoom: 20.5,
    pitch: 75,
    essential: true,
    duration: 12000,
  });

  set
```

Timeout(() => {}, 1000);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was answered in the github thread https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/13094 Issue had to do with setting up the render function. Needed to respect the X,Y,Z input order and in my case it was placed as translateY,translateX,translateZ

```
const l = new THREE.Matrix4()
  .makeTranslation(
    this.modelTransform.translateX,
    this.modelTransform.translateY,
    this.modelTransform.translateZ ?? 0
  )...
```